# How can I get a view of input as a complex tensor? RuntimeError: Tensor must have a last dimension with stride 1

Tags: python, pytorch, complex-numbers, stride

I have a tensor with 64 elements in pytorch and I want to convert it to a complex tensor with 32 elements. Order is important for me and everything should be in PyTorch so I can use it in my customized loss function:
the first half in my primary tensor (W) are my real numbers and the second half are my imaginary ones. so my final tensor should be like:

W_final = tensor(W[0]+jW[32], W[1]+jW[33], W[2]+jW[34], W[3]+jW[35], ... , W[31]+jW[63])

I tried this approach:

```
import torch
W_1 = = torch.reshape(W,(2,32)) #reshape W with shape (64) to W_1 with shape (2,32) 
W_2 = torch.transpose(W_1,0,1) #transpose W_1 to W_2 with shape (32,2), so I can use view_as_complex
W_final = torch.view_as_complex(W_2)
```

The problem is that with transpose, the stride also changes and I get this error:
`RuntimeError: Tensor must have a last dimension with stride 1`

Do know how can I deal with stride? or is there any way to reshape with different orders same as numpy?
or any other way to convert to complex?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to do with the non contiguous memory allocation for W_2 after you do reshape.
To handle this error you should call `.contiguous()` on W_2.
From Pytorch Docs:
" Strides are a list of integers: the k-th stride represents the jump in the memory necessary to go from one element to the next one in the k-th dimension of the Tensor. This concept makes it possible to perform many tensor operations efficiently."
Once you call `contiguous` all dimensions of returned tensor will have stride 1.

Here is a working sample code:

```
import torch
W = torch.randn(64)
W_2 = W.view(-1,32).permute(1,0).contiguous()
W_final = torch.view_as_complex(W_2)
```

First call `view` to reshape tensor to shape (2,32), then permute dimensions to transpose the result and call `contiguous`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Gil. you helped a lot.

Comment: My pleasure, Razi :)