# view size not compatible.. error in Google Colab

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am working with Pytorch on google colab and there is this very strange error.

```
     65 
     66         # flatten
---> 67         x = x.reshape(x.size(0), -1)
     68 
     69         x = self.dropout5(F.elu(self.bn5(self.fc1(x))))

RuntimeError: view size is not compatible with input tensor's size and stride (at least one dimension spans across two contiguous subspaces). Use .reshape(...) instead.
```

I have changed `view` to `reshape` but the error still persists. I have tried using `contiguous().view` (as many forums have suggested) as well but it doesn't work.

I call it strange because it has worked before but now suddenly it does not. I am almost certain that this is a google colab exclusive error. I have tried debugging using pdb trace but to no avail.

Any way to fix this?

Comment: It should be `x = x.view(-1)`, or `x = x.reshape(-1)`, or even `x = x.view(torch.prod(torch.tensor(x.shape)))`.

Comment: `---> 67         x = x.reshape(-1)`
@OriYardenPhD thank your the response.

 I am still met with the same error-

`RuntimeError: view size is not compatible with input tensor's size and stride (at least one dimension spans across two contiguous subspaces). Use .reshape(...) instead.`

Comment: @OriYardenPhD It seems like it is still being read as `view()` despite me changing it.  I am almost certain this is now a google Colab exclusive error.

And the worst part is that it worked once before.

Comment: here I found the reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63852258/how-can-i-get-a-view-of-input-as-a-complex-tensor-runtimeerror-tensor-must-hav